# GCloud proxy failure when same when works in web

Tags: proxy, gcloud, windows-credential-provider

I'm using Windows and GCP. My company uses an authenticated proxy. Normally, the browser is able to fetch the correct proxy settings without issue. However, gcloud asks for the proxy and so I set by answering the settings questions in

```
gcloud info --diagnostics
```

To test my settings, I changed my Windows settings to a manual proxy, set the proxy address to http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080. I signed into Edge and went to example.com and was prompted by proxy.mycompany.com for a proxy password. I gave it and then saw the content of example.com.

These same values I set to http_proxy, https_proxy and also provided to the above gcloud info --diagnostics. Yet it still gives me a proxy error when running one of the Python scripts.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the `gcloud config set` commands so that you can specify the username and password. Example `gcloud config set proxy/username [USERNAME]`  and `gcloud config set proxy/password [PASSWORD]` Refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings#proxy_configuration). If that works for you, post an answer showing your solution.

Comment: @JohnHanley I did try those and it still didn't work. I wish I had an undeniable way to prove I have the right settings. Also I chose proxy type HTTP

Comment: My suggestion is to show the gcloud config settings and the exact error message in your post. Your post does not have enough details to help indicate where the problem is. For problems like yours, I often fire up WireShark and look at the proxy traffic.